# most efficient way to find average using lodash

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I have an array of objects, the number of objects is variable -

```
var people = [{
  name: john,
  job: manager,
  salary: 2000
},
  {
  name: sam,
  job: manager,
  salary: 6000
},
  {
  name: frodo,
  job: janitor
}];
```

Whats the most elegant way to find the average of the salaries of all managers using lodash? ( I assume we have to check if an object is manager, as well as if the object has a salary property)

I was thinking in the below lines -

```
_(people).filter(function(name) {
    return name.occupation === "manager" && _(name).has("salary");}).pluck("salary").reduce(function(sum,num) { return sum+num });
```

But I am not sure if this is the right approach.

Comment: Is this code working?  The reduce doesn't seem to be finding avg, instead it is returning a sum of all salaries.

Answer (score 63):

Why all people gets over-complicated here?

```js
const people = [
  { name: 'Alejandro', budget: 56 },
  { name: 'Juan',      budget: 86 },
  { name: 'Pedro',     budget: 99 },
];

const average = _.meanBy(people, (p) => p.budget);
console.log(average);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

As per the docs: https://lodash.com/docs/#meanBy

Comment: Can be simplified to `let average = _.meanBy(people, 'budget');`. Also works only for v4.*

Comment: @Stalinko That makes it shorter, not simpler, when you use IDE then you can see the type of budget (in case of TypeScript), or you can use go to declaration, find references etc. the answer is great, what he could do to simplify it is use `p => p.budget`

Comment: @Stalinko not exactly, going with the arrow method it omits to do the calculation and using a middleware method to finding the 'budget' member, also as Almis said, the arrow enables IDEs to see the data type.

Comment: @FredericYesidPeñaSánchez let the people decide what they like more. Anyway there isn't big difference in both approaches.

Answer (score 20):

"efficient" is very ambiguous term. Saying "efficient" you can think about *performance*, or *readability*, or *conciseness* and so on. I think the most *readable* and *concise* solution is:

```
_(people).filter({ job: 'manager'}).filter('salary').reduce(function(a,m,i,p) {
    return a + m.salary/p.length;
},0);
```

The most *fast* solution is do not use loadash, nor any library, nor any `filter`, `reduce` methods at all. Use `for` loop instead:

```
var sum    = 0;
var count  = 0;
for (var i = 0, ii = people.length; i < ii; ++i) {
    var man = people[i];

    if (typeof man.salary !== 'undefined') {
        sum += man.salary;
        ++count;
    }
}
var avg = sum/count;
```

I think for the client side development *readability* is more important than *performance* in most cases , so I think first variant is most "efficient".

Comment: other than the clear error in the reduce which makes it return the sum and not the average in the OP's question, how is that different from his solution?  (really asking, no criticism intended)

Comment: `a + m.salary/p.length` - look at the `p.length` - that  makes result average, not sum.

Comment: @lascort You can try it yourself if you don't believe to me. Go to the [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs), open console, create `people` array, then copy/paste my solution.

Comment: I'm not saying it doesn't work, all I'm saying is that it seems to me like the same thing he did but in a different order. Except he clearly made a mistake in the reduce function, but I'm assuming that's just a typo. I may be mistaken though, I'm no expert at lodash, that's why I'm asking

Comment: @lascort The question was "most efficient way to find average using lodash". I think that this is the most "efficient" and elegant way. I think it's more clear then his own solution. Well, if someone has better ideas, they can write their own answers. And I even remove my answer if I find their solution better.

Comment: Code only answers can generally be improved by the addition of some explanatory text. In this case explaining both how this works and why you think it is the most efficient method.

Comment: @JasonAller Explanation is added.

Comment: Thank you for all the response. I understand that for will be more performant. But i was trying to learn lodash and functional applicative programming using it. The code that i wrote was returning just the sum. I stopped it there coz i did not know whether I was going in the right direction. I am not so familiar with underscore and lodash chaining using reduce and other functions

Comment: If the first solutions is the one with most readability I wouldn't use one character variable names.

Answer (score 9):

lodash v3:

`_.sum(people, 'salary') / people.length` (`people` mustn't be empty)

lodash v4:

`_.meanBy(people, 'salary')`

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about lowdash, but maybe a plain JS solution will help you get there:

```
console.log(people.reduce(function(values, obj) {
              if (obj.hasOwnProperty('salary')) {
                values.sum += obj.salary;
                values.count++;
                values.average = values.sum / values.count;
              }
              return values;
            }, {sum:0, count:0, average: void 0}).average
); // 4000
```

This passes an object to *reduce* as the *accumulator* that has three properties: the sum of salaries, the count of salaries, and the average so far. It iterates over all the objects, summing the salaries, counting how many there are and calculating the average on each iteration. Eventually it returns that object (the *accumulator*) and the *average* property is read.

Calling a single built–in method should be faster (i.e. more efficient) than calling 4 native functions. "Elegant" is in the eye of the beholder. ;-)

BTW, there are errors in the object literal, it should be:

```
var people = [{
  name: 'john',
  job: 'manager',
  salary: 2000
},
  {
  name: 'sam',
  job: 'manager',
  salary: 6000
},
  {
  name: 'frodo',
  job: 'janitor'
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function average(acc, ele, index) {
    return (acc + ele) / (index + 1);
}

var result = _.chain(people)
    .filter('job', 'manager')
    .map('salary')
    .reduce( average )
    .value();
```

Answer (score 1):

With the more functional `lodash` version (`lodash-fp`) and `es2015` you can to use arrow functions and auto curry to get a more flexible and functional flavored solution.

You can put it in an ugly one liner:

```
const result = _.flow(_.filter(['job', 'manager']), 
    e => _.sumBy('salary', e) / _.countBy(_.has('salary'), e).true)(people);
```

Or you can create a tidy DSL:

```
const hasSalary = _.has('salary');
const countWhenHasSalary = _.countBy(hasSalary);
const salarySum = _.sumBy('salary');
const salaryAvg = a => salarySum(a) / countWhenHasSalary(a).true;
const filterByJob = job => _.filter(['job', job]);
const salaryAvgByJob = job => _.flow(filterByJob(job), salaryAvg);

const result = salaryAvgByJob('manager')(people);
```

Answer (score 0):

Most clean (elegant) way I could think of was:

```
var salariesOfManagers = _(people).filter({job: 'manager'}).filter('salary').pluck('salary');
var averageSalary = salariesOfManagers.sum() / salariesOfManagers.value().length;
```

It takes sum of items and divides its with number of items, which is pretty much the definition of average.

Too bad that if you would like to make that to neat one-liner, the code will get less clear to read.

Answer (score 0):

Using [lodash/fp](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide) and ES2016/ES6 it can be done in a more functional way

```
const avg = flow(
    filter({job: 'manager'}), 
    map('salary'),
    mean
)

console.log(avg(people))
```

What you do is
1. Get all objects 'manager' type
2. Extract 'salary' property/field from them
3. Find average using mean function

Here is a full version of code for your convenience that runs on nodejs.

```
'use strict'
const _ = require('lodash/fp');

const {
    flow,
    filter,
    map,
    mean
} = _

const people = [{
    name: 'john',
    job: 'manager',
    salary: 2000
}, {
    name: 'sam',
    job: 'manager',
    salary: 6000
}, {
    name: 'frodo',
    job: 'janitor'
}];

const avg = flow(
    filter({job: 'manager'}), 
    map('salary'),
    mean
)

console.log(avg(people))
```